# How to recycle an IIS Application pool from a classic ASP page?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-8, application-pool

I need to programatically recycle an IIS Application pool from a classic ASP page.
How could I achieve that ?

I am able to do it from a VBS, but not from an ASP page.

So far, I have tried this code, which returns no error, but does nothing :

```
<%
Set objWShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objCmd = objWShell.Exec("%systemroot%\SysWow64\cmd.exe /c %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool /apppool.name:MyAppPoolNameHere")
    Set objCmd = nothing
Set objWShell = nothing
%>
```

I also have tried the following code (which works in VBS, but not inside an ASP page) :

```
<%
Set locator = Server.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set Service = Locator.connectserver("MyServerName", "root/MicrosoftIISv2")
Set APCollection = Service.InstancesOf("IISApplicationPool")

Response.write APCollection.count

For Each APInstance In APCollection
    Response.Write "<br>" & APInstance.Name
    APInstance.Recycle
Next
%>
```

Many thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: You will need to run the ASP page in the context of an account with elevated privileges.

Comment: @Lankymart, Yes, that is what I have finished to understand. I do not like this solution, but it was the only one. For example, running the Application Pool using the "LocalService" identity makes my ASP page work. That is so bad and not ideal considering the security implications.

Comment: In the good old days, you would create a VB6 ActiveX DLL to contain the high-priv code and run this under COM, registering it to run-as s user identity with the higher privs. In this was you avoid the concern of giving all ASP pages the elevated permissions.

Comment: Absolutely true.. But these good old days are over, ans I left my VB6 CD on a shelf :-( So, using the "LocalService" identity makes the code of my initial quesiton correctly work, but curiously, some methods and properties are not available for the Application Pool, even in VBScript, like *.getState*, and the properties *.AutoStart* and others... Only the *.Recycle*, *.Start*, and *.Stop* methods seems to work.. Is the documentation broken ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms690608

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue long ago, ended up writing code that edits the web.config file, and thus causing automatic recycle of the application pool.

To make it work you need to grant full permissions for the IUSR account over the web.config file, I don't think those are given by default.

Code is as follows: (lots of debug, you can remove all the Response.Write lines)

```vbs
<% Option Explicit %>
<% Response.Buffer = True %>
<%
Const FILE_PATH="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Web.config"
Dim objFSo, objFile, strData
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Response.Write("File: " & FILE_PATH & ", Exist? " & objFSO.FileExists(FILE_PATH) & "<br />")
Response.Flush()
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FILE_PATH)
strData = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
Response.Write("Got " & Len(strData) & " bytes of data<br />")
Response.Flush()
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(FILE_PATH)
objFile.Write(strData)
objFile.Close
Response.Write("Success")
Response.Flush()
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Not directly relevant to my original question, but still confirms the need to run the Application Pool under a Highly-Privileged Identity user account.